# Drupal: Can see data in admin preview but not in views

Tags: drupal

In drupal admin (admin/build/views/edit/view_name) the preview return something like 50 rows of date then when I get into the view it returns 50 rows of empty strings.

-The field values im trying to see just got added in a new column in my database table.

-All users have access to this view.

-I cleared the cache.

Does anyone knows what could be wrong?

Thank you

Comment: sometimes having access to the view isn't enough. Do your users have the correct permissions set under /admin/user/permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CCK and have Content Permissions turned on, make sure users have permission to view the CCK fields /admin/user/permissions

Comment: Yes they also have permissions.